# is there any way to control inputsplit in map reduce

Tags: hadoop, dictionary, mapreduce

I have lots of small(150-300 KB) text file 9000 per hour,I need to process them through map reduce. I created a simple MR which will process all the file and create single output file. when i run job this job for 1 hour data, it took 45 min. i started digging reason of poor performance, i found it takes as many input-split as the number of file. as i am guessing one reason for poor performance.

is there any way to control the input split by which i can say 1000 file would be entertained by one input split/Map.

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop is designed for huge files in small numbers and not the other way. There are some ways to get around it like [preprocessing](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/02/the-small-files-problem/) the data, using the [CombineFileInputFormat](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/CombineFileInputFormat.html).